# InvalidRegistration -> NotRegistered when first notification in foreground app

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Doing the FCM implementation, an unusual behavior is detected when sending notifications when the application is in a foreground state on iOS from postman.

It should throw the notification to iOS user but it's not sending any notification rath it throws

For detail please visit
[Github Issue Link](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11788)

Comment: If you're testing this on simulator then you need to reinstall the app and try again, this will work only one time
you can try the same on real device

Comment: i have already did this multiple times any other suggestions?

Comment: this issue is due to payload, in ios you need pass few other arguments 
you can test the same codebase with any other tool like send notification from nodeJs App or any other app, where you can authenticate the notification from firebase admin sdk json file

Comment: have you seen the github link which i have provided ?

Comment: Yes I saw that and I faced the same issue before 2-3 months, I was sending the notification from postman that time. But after some research I go with nodeJs and this never happened again in all the application mode

Comment: Tried using .net api but no luck .Can you tell me which things are needed in apple developer account to be configured before sending notifications

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255788/discussion-between-abhishek-karad-and-akshay-gupta).